# Python: make consistent 3D plot out of point values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, mplot3d

In a 2D plane, I have a set of `nxn` points defined by their `(x,y)` coordinates. For each point, there exists a certain quantity that I want to plot as a 3D surface. How can I do it in such a way that each point is assigned the relevant value in the plot? I ask because I am getting a messed up plot.

I'll explain myself better. I have:

1. A dictionary of positions for `10x10=100` points in the plane:

`dict1={0:(0, 0), 1:(0, 1), 2:(0, 2), ..., 99:(9,9)}`

2. A dictionary of values that are going to be associated with said points:

`dict2=OrderedDict([(0, 369670), (1, 370622), (2, 267034), ..., (99, 217500)])`

3. The merging of `dict1` and `dict2`, where each value is associated with the correct point, each point being labelled based on its coordinates:

`merged_dict={dict1[k]: v for k, v in dict2.items()}`

`merged_dict={(0,0):369670, (0,1):370622, (0,2):267034, ..., (9,9): 217500}`

The intended 3D plot has point coordinates as X and Y and Z coming from `merged_dict`. This is my attempt:

```
#3D plot
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
inds=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ..., (9,9)] #The coordinates of each point -> len(inds)=100

X=[]
for k in range(len(inds)):
    X.append(int(inds[k][0]))
Y=X

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

merged_dict = {dict1[k]: v for k, v in dict2.items()}

Z = merged_dict.values()

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.winter, linewidth=0, antialiased=True)

ax.set_zlim(0, 900000)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

plt.show()
```

**The plot I get is wrong** in that it features a messed up surface. The intended outcome is a symmetrical, bell-shaped surface peaking at over 800,000 in correspondence with points (4,4), (5,4), (4,5), (5,5). Instead, the results make me think that Z values are not correctly associated with the relevant X, Y coordinates. **How to fix this?**
[image]

**EDIT**

These are the actual data involved:

```
In[1]: merged_dict
Out[1]: 
{(0, 0): 369670,
 (0, 1): 370622,
 (0, 2): 267034,
 (0, 3): 169500,
 (0, 4): 116014,
 (0, 5): 116014,
 (0, 6): 169500,
 (0, 7): 267034,
 (0, 8): 370622,
 (0, 9): 369670,
 (1, 0): 370622,
 (1, 1): 491950,
 (1, 2): 456750,
 (1, 3): 370180,
 (1, 4): 308118,
 (1, 5): 308118,
 (1, 6): 370180,
 (1, 7): 456750,
 (1, 8): 491950,
 (1, 9): 370622,
 (2, 0): 267034,
 (2, 1): 456750,
 (2, 2): 542718,
 (2, 3): 554980,
 (2, 4): 543588,
 (2, 5): 543588,
 (2, 6): 554980,
 (2, 7): 542718,
 (2, 8): 456750,
 (2, 9): 267034,
 (3, 0): 169500,
 (3, 1): 370180,
 (3, 2): 554980,
 (3, 3): 689848,
 (3, 4): 759272,
 (3, 5): 759272,
 (3, 6): 689848,
 (3, 7): 554980,
 (3, 8): 370180,
 (3, 9): 169500,
 (4, 0): 116014,
 (4, 1): 308118,
 (4, 2): 543588,
 (4, 3): 759272,
 (4, 4): 888268,
 (4, 5): 888268,
 (4, 6): 759272,
 (4, 7): 543588,
 (4, 8): 308118,
 (4, 9): 116014,
 (5, 0): 116014,
 (5, 1): 308118,
 (5, 2): 543588,
 (5, 3): 759272,
 (5, 4): 888268,
 (5, 5): 888268,
 (5, 6): 759272,
 (5, 7): 543588,
 (5, 8): 308118,
 (5, 9): 116014,
 (6, 0): 169500,
 (6, 1): 370180,
 (6, 2): 554980,
 (6, 3): 689848,
 (6, 4): 759272,
 (6, 5): 759272,
 (6, 6): 689848,
 (6, 7): 554980,
 (6, 8): 370180,
 (6, 9): 169500,
 (7, 0): 267034,
 (7, 1): 456750,
 (7, 2): 542718,
 (7, 3): 554980,
 (7, 4): 543588,
 (7, 5): 543588,
 (7, 6): 554980,
 (7, 7): 542718,
 (7, 8): 456750,
 (7, 9): 267034,
 (8, 0): 370622,
 (8, 1): 491950,
 (8, 2): 456750,
 (8, 3): 370180,
 (8, 4): 308118,
 (8, 5): 308118,
 (8, 6): 370180,
 (8, 7): 456750,
 (8, 8): 491950,
 (8, 9): 370622,
 (9, 0): 369670,
 (9, 1): 370622,
 (9, 2): 267034,
 (9, 3): 169500,
 (9, 4): 116014,
 (9, 5): 116014,
 (9, 6): 169500,
 (9, 7): 267034,
 (9, 8): 370622,
 (9, 9): 369670}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess a problem in line `Y=X`. `X, Y` are lists. When you write `Y=X`, it means `Y` is a reference to `X`. You need to make a copy, i.e.:

```
Y = []
numpy.copy(Y,X)
```

Test this variant and write what would happened. Otherwise post data for merged_dict to test plot on real values.

**UPDATE:**

Look at figure, is it correct?
Array `Z` have to be 2d array but in your code it is 1d list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

X = np.arange(0,10,1)
Y = np.arange(0,10,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
merged_dict = {(0, 0): 369670,
 (0, 1): 370622,
 (0, 2): 267034,
 ...
 (9, 8): 370622,
 (9, 9): 369670}

Z = np.array(merged_dict.values()).reshape(10,10)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.winter, linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
ax.set_zlim(0, 900000)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Problem occurs because of you data store in dict, but dict does not sorted by indexes. To load values to array `Z`:

```
Z = np.zeros((10,10))

for key in merged_dict:
    i = key[0]
    j = key[1]
    Z[i][j] = int(merged_dict[key])
```

As a result, you get:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change the output. Check my edit for actual data.

Comment: OK, post data for merged_dict to test plot on real values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort, but it is not the correct surface. It should have a bell-shaped peak right in the center and should decrease sensibly at the corners. I am very curious about the `Z=np.array` line: when `reshape` is called, does it actually preserve the connection between the x, y coordinates of a point and the corresponding Z value? I think it does not, and that's why the outcome is not correct. Thoughts?

Comment: Why not? Reshape makes geometry of your array as you want. But you data in a dict and it is not sorted by indexes (sorry, I forgot about this property of a dict). It is mean you need manually to add data to corresponding indexes of Z, like in UPDATE 2.

Comment: This is odd. The Z object is a 2D array, while X and Y are 1D. As a result, I get an error: `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`. This points at the line where `surf` is created. Did you not have the same error? Did you transform the Z array into something else BEFORE making the plot?